# How to use Adobe Creative Cloud Font in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, adobe, adobe-cc

I have Adobe Creative Cloud and have activated several fonts. I verify that they appear and work in other applications (e.g., MS Word, Adobe Illustrator, etc.). However, I cannot get the Adobe Font to work with ggplot2.

Normally after I install a new font (e.g., from Google fonts), I can run `extrafont::font_import()`, and then `extrafont::loadfonts()`, and everything works great. Not so for Adobe fonts. When I run `extrafont::fonts()` none of the Adobe fonts are listed, and I get an error from ggplot2 that I don't get when using non-Adobe fonts:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Papyrus"))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Museo"))
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)): no font could
#> be found for family "Museo"
#> Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : no
#> font could be found for family "Museo"
#> Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : polygon edge not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is there a way to use Adobe Creative Cloud fonts with ggplot2?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: macOS 11.0.1 (Big Sur)